# I need to build a specific form like this

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I searched for form plugins for Wordpress but i can't find a form maker which fits this case. I need to make a form like the screenshot, which users can fill in and send to a mail address. Is there any template or whatsoever for this case? Or else i need to write all the code by myself.

Thanks in advance!!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vc1cw.png

Comment: Homework to do Joris?

Comment: Can you show us what alternatives have you tried? Did you even tried to Google it up? Any plugins to do special forms and such? This site is to help with code, not provide it.

Answer (score 0):

A few good plugins that I'm sure can handle this for you:

Contact form 7: http://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/

Gravity forms:
http://www.gravityforms.com/

Might not look EXACTLY like yours but I'm sure with some adjustments on the CSS you can get it pretty darn close.

Answer (score 0):

There is a really good and easy to use plugin called [Contact Form 7](http://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/) - this should meet your requirements and is simple to configure.